# 前の値を使用した計算

Tags: ruby

下記のようなメソッドがあった場合example3, 6, 9をそれぞれ出力する際に、example6, example9を出力する時にもメソッドexample1から計算を始めるのですがこれだと時間がかかってしまいます。
1度example3を計算したらその結果をexample6, 9にそのまま当てはめることはできるのでしょうか。
私ではなかなか思いつきません。
何かありましたらアドバイスお願いします。

```
def example1a
    (6 + 5 + 9 + 10 + 4 + 6 +) / 6
end

def example1b
   a = example1a + 2/13 * (8 - example1a) 
   b = a + 2/13 * (9 - a)
   c = b + 2/13 * (7 - b)
   d = c + 2/13 * (3 - c)
   e = d + 2/13 * (8 - d)
   f = e + 2/13 * (5 - e)
   g = f + 2/13 * (4 - f)
   h = g + 2/13 * (10 - g)
   i = h + 2/13 * (9 - h)
   j = i + 2/13 * (6 - i)
   k = j + 2/13 * (7 - j)
   l = k + 2/13 * (8 - k)
end

def example2a
    (5 + 9 + 12 + 3 + 4 + 9 + 6 + 4 + 3 + 4) / 10
end

def example2b
    a = example2a + 2/27 * (5 - example2a) 
    b = a + 2/27 * (5 - a)
    c = b + 2/27 * (4 - b)
    d = c + 2/27 * (4 - c)
    e = d + 2/27 * (9 - d)
    f = e + 2/27 * (8 - e)
    g = f + 2/27 * (4 - f)
    h = g + 2/27 * (3 - g)
    i = h + 2/27 * (6 - h)
    j = i + 2/27 * (7 - i)
    k = j + 2/27 * (5 - j)
    l = k + 2/27 * (4 - k)
end

def example3
    example1b - example2b
end


def example4a
    (6 + 5 + 9 + 10 + 4 + 6) / 6
end

def example4b
   a = example4a + 2/13 * (8 - example4a) 
   b = a + 2/13 * (9 - a)
   c = b + 2/13 * (7 - b)
   d = c + 2/13 * (3 - c)
   e = d + 2/13 * (8 - d)
   f = e + 2/13 * (5 - e)
   g = f + 2/13 * (4 - f)
   h = g + 2/13 * (10 - g)
   i = h + 2/13 * (9 - h)
   j = i + 2/13 * (6 - i)
   k = j + 2/13 * (7 - j)
   l = k + 2/13 * (8 - k)
end

def example5a
    (5 + 9 + 12 + 3 + 4 + 9 + 6 + 4 + 3 + 4) / 10
end

def example5b
    a = example5a + 2/27 * (5 - example5a) 
    b = a + 2/27 * (5 - a)
    c = b + 2/27 * (4 - b)
    d = c + 2/27 * (4 - c)
    e = d + 2/27 * (9 - d)
    f = e + 2/27 * (8 - e)
    g = f + 2/27 * (4 - f)
    h = g + 2/27 * (3 - g)
    i = h + 2/27 * (6 - h)
    j = i + 2/27 * (7 - i)
    k = j + 2/27 * (5 - j)
    l = k + 2/27 * (4 - k)
end

def example6
    example4b - example5b
end


def example7a
    (6 + 5 + 9 + 10 + 4 + 6) / 6
end

def example7b
   a = example7a + 2/13 * (8 - example7a) 
   b = a + 2/13 * (9 - a)
   c = b + 2/13 * (7 - b)
   d = c + 2/13 * (3 - c)
   e = d + 2/13 * (8 - d)
   f = e + 2/13 * (5 - e)
   g = f + 2/13 * (4 - f)
   h = g + 2/13 * (10 - g)
   i = h + 2/13 * (9 - h)
   j = i + 2/13 * (6 - i)
   k = j + 2/13 * (7 - j)
   l = k + 2/13 * (8 - k)
end

def example8a
    (5 + 9 + 12 + 3 + 4 + 9 + 6 + 4 + 3 + 4) / 10
end

def example8b
    a = example8a + 2/27 * (5 - example8a) 
    b = a + 2/27 * (5 - a)
    c = b + 2/27 * (4 - b)
    d = c + 2/27 * (4 - c)
    e = d + 2/27 * (9 - d)
    f = e + 2/27 * (8 - e)
    g = f + 2/27 * (4 - f)
    h = g + 2/27 * (3 - g)
    i = h + 2/27 * (6 - h)
    j = i + 2/27 * (7 - i)
    k = j + 2/27 * (5 - j)
    l = k + 2/27 * (4 - k)
end

def example9
    example7b - example8b
end

puts exanmple3, exanmple6, exanmple9
```

Comment: 計算式が `+` で終わっていたり、 演算子 `-` が EN DASH(U+2013) になっていたり、`example` が `exanmple` になっていたり、などなど、書き間違いが多いので修正をお願いします。

Comment: `exanmple`については説明部分でのタイプミスだと思われたので、私の方で修正してしまいました。

Comment: サンプルはなるべく [最小限であること](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) を心がけると、コードの見通しがよくなり意図も伝わりやすいと思います。今回の例なら`example6`までの記述でやりたいことの「再計算せずに～」は伝わりますし、関数内部の計算も3行程度あれば十分ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 書き間違いの件とコードの書き方の件は申し訳ありませんでした。以後気をつけます。回答して下さったやり方で上手くいきました。見づらいコードの中回答して頂きありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

たとえば、

```
def example2a
    return @example2a_result if @example2a_result
    @example2a_result = (5 + 9 + 12 + 3 + 4 + 9 + 6 + 4 + 3 + 4) / 10
end
```

みたいな感じにすると、2回目以降の呼び出し時には計算せずに `@example2a_result` の値を返すだけになります。

Answer (score 1):

- 関数でのメモ化を行い、一度計算した値を計算し直さずに返せるようにする
- main的な関数を作り、その中で計算結果を変数に保存する。そして、各関数で引数を取り、他の計算結果を使えるようにする

といった方法が推奨されます。